# Ubuntu 13.04 installation with Raid 1

Tags: 13.04, partitioning, raid

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 on IBM System x 3250 M4 with RAID 1. During Partitioning.

After

1. Select Manual as the partition method.
2. Select the first hard drive, and agree to `Create a new empty partition table on this device?`.
3. Select the `FREE SPACE` on the first drive then select `Create a new partition`.
4. Select the Size of the partition. This partition will be the swap partition, and a general rule for swap size is twice that of RAM. Enter the partition size, then choose Primary, then Beginning.

   **At this stage**, there is no Primary to be chosen from, only the beginning.

Please give me more instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you to get setup [Using GParted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276014/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-server-with-raid1)

It seems you need `GParted` to Do this ..

Here to the Instillation Steps in official Site

[Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html)

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. I'm very new to Ubuntu. Would you please give me some more details how to do the partition with GParted before Ubuntu Installation?

Comment: Hope this will Help You a lot 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/how-do-i-repartition-with-gparted